# UICollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a view that has four collection views. I am trying to detect the cell on which I receive the long press gesture. I have gesture recognizer installed and it's working fine for the collection view at the top(physically not hierarchically) of the view but not working for the rest of them.

Try following code:

```
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

NSIndexPath *indexPath;
if ([self.TopCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p]){
    indexPath = [self.TopCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    _lilCell = (ArticlePanelViewCell *)[self.TopCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"top");
}else if([self.MiddleCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p]){
    indexPath = [self.MiddleCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    _lilCell = (ArticlePanelViewCell *)[self.MiddleCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"middle");
}else if([self.BottomCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p]){
    indexPath = [self.BottomCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    _lilCell = (ArticlePanelViewCell *)[self.BottomCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"bottom");
}else if([self.ExtraCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p]){
    indexPath = [self.ExtraCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    _lilCell = (ArticlePanelViewCell *)[self.ExtraCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"bottom");
}else {
    NSLog(@"Long press detected outside the content panel area");
}
```

It's working for the TopCollectionView and not the rest of them. The point p does show the correct co-ordinates. The gesture recognizer callback is in the viewcontroller containing 4 collection views as it's subviews.

Comment: Does the "Long press detected outside the content panel area" log get printed ?

Comment: Yep, for all the touches outside the top collection view, "Long press detected outside the content panel area" get's printed.

Comment: I mean when you press on Any `CollectionView` (besides the top one) it get printed

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the layout so I can have a picture of it ?

Comment: They are 4 horizontally scrollable collection views from top to the bottom of the view. I can't post a screenshot here as it does contain branding info.

Comment: View Hierarchy atleast ?

Comment: ViewController->View->TopCollectionView and the same for the rest of the 3 collection views.

Comment: So all the Collections are in the UIView (No UIScrollViews etc) Right ?

Comment: Yes, there is no scrollview in between.

Comment: What is the topCollection's frame.origin ?

Comment: (0,128) (0, 429) (0, 675) and (0, 868) for all four respectively from top to bottom and all of them span the entire width of the screen.

Comment: Well, you are passing the point in the View's coordinate system,
But collection view wants this point in it's coordinate system.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathForItemAtPoint:

Comment: So you have to convert the p to each collection view's coordinate system

Comment: You should know whether the `CGPoint p` is inside one of the collection's frame and then convert it to the collection's coordinate

Comment: But then why would it work for even the top one?

Comment: I don't know I can make a lot of assumptions: maybe because it's coordinate system is closer to the parent view's coordinate system so it gets the touch invoked, but if you will log on what cell it is done it will probably be offfset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathForItemAtPoint)

The method `indexPathForItemAtPoint` expect to take `CGPoint` in its coordinate system.

So to solve you problem you should add a little more code.

First you should recognize in which collectionView `frame` has the `CGPoint` inside.

You can use this method `bool CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint point);`

Then when you know in which collectionView the touch was you should convert it to it's coordinate system

```
CGPoint p = [self.view convertPoint:p toView:collectionView];
```

And then invoke

```
indexPath = [self.theCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
```

**Please note:**
That if you tap between the cells (and not directly on the actual cell) you won't get the cell's `indexPath`

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thank you very much for a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was: If you have set an inset for your UICollectionView using

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
```

then you will need to adjust the value of your CGPoint.x accordingly, otherwise *indexPathForItemAtPoint:* will not find any item in the space where the inset lyes.